# Does LinkedIn have a specific option or setting for when you're looking for work and want recruiters to contact you?

Tags: linkedin

In LinkedIn is there a setting for when you are looking for work and want people to contact you with job offers? For example is there a specific place to specify it's ok for recruiters to contact you? I may be remembering wrong but I thought there was and now I can't find it. Maybe I'm thinking of craigslist how they have the option "ok to be solicited for other offers" or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes. In case the URL below changes, the article's title is **Sharing Your Career Interests with Recruiters**

https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/67405/sharing-your-career-interests-with-recruiters?lang=en

The steps are as follows:

- Click on "View Profile" under your icon
- In the dashboard section, click on Career Interests
- Once you're in the *Career interests page*, you can now use the toggle to turn the feature on/off